# Drop rows in a pandas dataframe by criteria from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe containing scores for a competition as well as a column that counts what number entry for each person.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Jim', 'John','Jim', 'John','Jim','John','Jim','John','Jim','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack'],'Score': [10,8,9,3,5,0, 1, 2,3, 4,5,6,8,9]})
df['Entry_No'] = df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount() + 1
df
```

[image]

Then I have another table that stores data on the maximum number of entries that each person can have:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Jim', 'Jack'],'Limit': [2,3,1]})
df2
```

[image]

I am trying to drop rows from `df` where the entry number is greater than the `Limit` according to each person in `df2` so that my expected output is this:

[image]

If there are any ideas on how to help me achieve this that would be fantastic! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to create another dataframe and drop columns by your condition:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, on="Name", how="left")
df3[df3["Entry_No"] <= df3["Limit"]][df.columns].reset_index(drop=True)
    Name  Score  Entry_No
0   John     10         1
1    Jim      8         1
2   John      9         2
3    Jim      3         2
4    Jim      0         3
5   Jack      5         1
```

I used `how="left"` to keep the order of `df` and `reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the index of the resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the 2 dataframes, and then drop with a condition:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Jim', 'John','Jim', 'John','Jim','John','Jim','John','Jim','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack'],'Score': [10,8,9,3,5,0, 1, 2,3, 4,5,6,8,9]})
df['Entry_No'] = df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount() + 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Jim', 'Jack'],'Limit': [2,3,1]})
df2 = df2.set_index('Name')

df = df.join(df2, on='Name')
df.drop(df[df.Entry_No>df.Limit].index, inplace = True)
```

gives the expected output